# Tomcat localhost private ip link is not accessible by another PC in same network

Tags: windows-7, ip, tomcat, port, localhost

My PC has the IP 192.168.1.185

The URL http://192.168.1.185:8080/projectname is not accessible by another computer in the same network having the IP 192.168.1.135.

I have disabled IIS already through which the link was accessible. But Through tomcat it is not accessible.

I have already enabled the port in firewall settings.

Comment: Did you restart Tomcat after disabling IIS so it can bind to 8080? Did you enable "outside" connections in your Tomcat config?

Comment: I have restarted tomcat and the thing is that appart from the same PC, the link is not accessible anywhere. please help with this.

Comment: Check the output of `netstat -anp` if Tomcat is listening on `192.168.1.185:8080`. If yes: it is almost always a firewall issue,

Comment: I get this by running such command. https://paste.pics/f8378327ce2f3e679bfce52565f88d31

Comment: whoops, sorry: `netstat -an`

Comment: We get this by such command. We have tried these ports to run that link.https://paste.pics/ef65d3e574ffbf3ff46c3e703a845a16

Comment: Double check your firewall and IIS. Also check your Tomcat access logs.